# Incorrect barcode encoding data matrix

Tags: xamarin, barcode, zxing, datamatrix

I'm developing an app on Xamarin where I need to render some strings to 2D barcodes. I'm using [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) to do the render.

I can render properly QR codes but the issue I'm having is with the Data Matrix format.

I attach two images, when I tried to encode the value "1234" I expect the first result but instead I'm getting the second one.

[image: Expected]
[image: Result]

Any idea of why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to specify width and height in writer.encode method? It should automatically fit the barcode into the given size

Comment: @EugeneM Yes, I tried setting the width and height, I get the same result, the issue is not the size, is that it doesn't render what you would expect to render.